# lastInsertId() for UPDATE in Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, prepared-statement

```
$query = $database->prepare("UPDATE table SET value = value WHERE value = '$value'");
$query_1->execute();
$database->connection->lastInsertId();
```

The code above does not work. The value I am trying to get is primary key auto increment.

As lastInsertId() suggests by its name, it may be intended for insert only. If so, what is the proper way to achieve the same goal on an UPDATE?

The value I wish to return is the primary key of the table, if the update has occurred.

Something like..

```
lastUpadteId()



  $query_1 = $database->connection->prepare("UPDATE accounts SET traffic = traffic + '$file_size', id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id) WHERE primary_key = '$account_id'");
  $query_1->execute();
  echo $database->connection->lastInsertId();
```

Throws...

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'' in

Comment: try this query: "UPDATE table SET value = value WHERE value = '$value', id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)"

Comment: @ceakki Thanks but how exactly do I get the value to use?

Comment: @ceakki Tried and it throws Uncaught exception.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. The query should be: "UPDATE table SET value = value, id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id) WHERE value = '$value'"

Comment: You will receive the id of the updated row in $database->connection->lastInsertId();

Comment: @ceakki Ok, tried that, still throws exception. See my update above for actual code and exception please.

Comment: well, replace id with primary_key. I supposed that `id` is your primary key

Comment: @ceakki It works. I have to say out of all the questions I've ever posted you are the ONLY one who could answer correctly and without being a little ass hole like most people on here! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LAST_INSERT_ID() doesn't work on UPDATE as it works on INSERT. But you can still get the id of the updated row using LAST_INSERT_ID() after an update. Here is the way your query should be written:

```
UPDATE table 
SET
  value = value, 
  primary_key = LAST_INSERT_ID(primary_key) 
WHERE value = 'some value'
```

Does it look strange for you `primary_key = LAST_INSERT_ID(primary_key)`? Then read this from MySQL Manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: If the explanation for not returning last UPDATED id is "you might update several items at once", how comes when it INSERTS, which can also happen for several items at once, it returns at least the first(last) ID? This is IMO a weird excuse for not returning last updated id just natively. Thanks for the resolution, it works great. 
Of course, if someone updates several things at once, that ID will not be an array of updated items, but neither it is when we insert several items at once, so that is really a moot reason provided by others as of why this shouldn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your statement, it may update more than one record. So get the last update ID isn't a good idea.

You can use a SELECT statement to get all the ID **before** update.

```
SELECT ID FROM table WHERE value = '$value'
```

Comment: Good point but actually no, only one record will be returned in this case.